# How do core system apps call hidden methods without reflection?

Tags: android, android-source

Normally, you can't direcly call Android APIs that are hidden (with the `@hide` annotation) from an app. You must use reflection to call such a method.

But some of the apps that are included in AOSP call hidden methods directly. How can I do this too for an app I add to the AOSP build tree?

Comment: These methods are hidden for a reason. You should not call them at all.

Comment: They were build with modified Android source code, which does not `hide` anything. You can investigate in that direction, and get the modified `android.jar` (or something like that) as well. Then you will be able to use hidden methods too.

Answer (score 2):

An app inside the AOSP build tree can call hidden methods if you comment out the following line in `Android.mk`:

`LOCAL_SDK_VERSION := current`